# mongodb dump data to another directory

Tags: mongodb

I understand I can dump data with this common

```
mongodump --db mydb
```

This command will dump all mydb collections data to ./dump/mydb. But I would like to dump data to another directory I named (say /home/user/mydb)

I have tried with --dbpath and --directoryperdb options and it seems not what I  want

Is there a way to do this?

./mongodump --help

Export MongoDB data to BSON files.

options:

```
 --help                   produce help message
  -v [ --verbose ]         be more verbose (include multiple times for more
                           verbosity e.g. -vvvvv)
  --version                print the program's version and exit
  -h [ --host ] arg        mongo host to connect to ( <set name>/s1,s2 for
                           sets)
  --port arg               server port. Can also use --host hostname:port
  --ipv6                   enable IPv6 support (disabled by default)
  -u [ --username ] arg    username
  -p [ --password ] arg    password
  --dbpath arg             directly access mongod database files in the given
                           path, instead of connecting to a mongod  server -
                           needs to lock the data directory, so cannot be used
                           if a mongod is currently accessing the same path
  --directoryperdb         if dbpath specified, each db is in a separate
                           directory
  --journal                enable journaling
  -d [ --db ] arg          database to use
  -c [ --collection ] arg  collection to use (some commands)
  -o [ --out ] arg (=dump) output directory or "-" for stdout
  -q [ --query ] arg       json query
  --oplog                  Use oplog for point-in-time snapshotting
  --repair                 try to recover a crashed database
  --forceTableScan         force a table scan (do not use $snapshot)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the -o option:

```
  -o [ --out ] arg (=dump) output directory or "-" for stdout
```

That will let you specify where the output goes.